# Wordpress Single Page SSL

Tags: ajax, wordpress, encryption, ssl

Ok, we have all seen this question a million times, but I am looking for an updated answer.

How can we have a single page encrypted with SSL on a Wordpress install? Even further, how can we make that single page communicate with the server via SSL?

Note: You cannot use plugins to accomplish this. I have seen what is out there, and personally think all of them are inefficient when it comes to accomplishing this. The best solution I have seen thus far is using an if statement in the wp-config.php file at page load. But does this solve the AJAX issue?

Comment: If you've dished out the cash for an SSL certificate, you might as well make the whole site HTTPS.

Comment: But isn't that less efficient? Is there not a heavy load on both the server and client when using SSL?

Comment: With modern servers, it's pretty minimal. It used to be a consideration years ago.

Comment: If this is the case, then that may be the option. I just always thought it was a bad idea. Perhaps I need to do more research in that respect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this seems to be in the wp-config.php file using:

```
if( !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ) {
    define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://yourdomain.com' );
    define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://yourdomain.com' );
}
```

If someone has a better way, I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm old school, so I would probably do it with a .htaccess rule that redirects to the https version. As far has having it *submit* as https, that a matter of having the form's `action=something` do the right thing.

All of this assumes that you *do* have an SSL cert properly set up on the server.

Comment: Well submitting the form as you stated is not paying attention to the SSL part of the question. Htaccess may work, but not sure if it is the best solution with a Wordpress installation.

Comment: @Petter, Sorry, meant not paying attention to the AJAX part of the question.

Comment: @ceejayoz, htaccess fowards the page to SSL fine. But in Wordpress, the site operates off of 2 main stored variables. site_url, and blog_url. It will cause issues with the AJAX side of things.

Comment: @Chris: Sorry, I glossed right over that. On subscription sites I've done we didn't try to keep a list of which pages wanted to be SSL, so the links were to the non-secure pages and the server just did a redirect as needed. This was a Django site and we did it in middleware, so the rough equivalent would be in wp-config.php.